# Digit Product Sequences

Tags: code-golf, sequence, number-theory

Here's an interesting sequence discovered by Paul Loomis, a mathematician at Bloomsburg University. From [his page](https://facstaff.bloomu.edu/ploomis/sequences.html) on this sequence:

Define
`f(n) = f(n-1) + (the product of the nonzero digits of f(n-1))`
`f(0) = x`, with `x` as any positive integer, written in base 10.

So, starting with `f(0)=1`, you get the following sequence
`1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 22, 26, 38, 62, 74, 102, 104, ...`

So far, so standard. The interesting property comes into play when you take any *other* integer as the starting point, eventually the sequence converges into a point along the above `x=1` sequence. For example, starting with `x=3` yields
`3, 6, 12, 14, 18, 26, 38, 62, 74, 102, ...`

Here are some more sequences, each shown only until they reach `102`:

```
5, 10, 11, 12, 14, 18, 26, 38, 62, 74, 102, ...
7, 14, 18, 26, 38, 62, 74, 102, ...
9, 18, 26, 38, 62, 74, 102, ...
13, 16, 22, 26, 38, 62, 74, 102, ...
15, 20, 22, 26, 38, 62, 74, 102, ...
17, 24, 32, 38, 62, 74, 102, ...
19, 28, 44, 60, 66, 102, ...
```

He conjectured, and empirically proved up to `x=1,000,000`, that this property (i.e., that all input numbers converge to the same sequence) holds true.

### The Challenge

Given a positive input integer `0 < x < 1,000,000`, output the number where the `f(x)` sequence converges to the `f(1)` sequence. For example, for `x=5`, this would be `26`, since that's the first number in common to both sequences.

```
 x output
 1 1
 5 26
19 102
63 150056
```

### Rules

- If applicable, you can assume that the input/output will fit in your language's native Integer type.
- The input and output can be given by [any convenient method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>81</s> 67 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @l4m2*

```javascript
f=(n,x=1)=>x<n?f(x,n):x>n?f(+[...n+''].reduce((p,i)=>p*i||p)+n,x):n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYjT6fC1lDT1q7CJs8@TaNCJ0/TqsIOxNSO1tPTy9NWV4/VK0pNKU1O1dAo0MkEqizQyqypKdDUBurUtMr7n5yfV5yfk6qXk5@ukaZhqKnJhSpiiiFiaIkhZGasqfkfAA)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (n,                   // n = current value for the 1st sequence, initialized to input
        x = 1) =>         // x = current value for the 2nd sequence, initialized to 1
  x < n ?                 // if x is less than n:
    f(x, n)               //   swap the sequences by doing a recursive call to f(x, n)
  :                       // else:
    x > n ?               //   if x is greater than n:
      f(                  //     do a recursive call with the next term of the 1st sequence:
        +[...n + '']      //       coerce n to a string and split it
        .reduce((p, i) => //       for each digit i in n:
          p * i || p      //         multiply p by i, or let p unchanged if i is zero
        ) + n,            //       end of reduce(); add n to the result
        x                 //       let x unchanged
      )                   //     end of recursive call
    :                     //   else:
      n                   //     return n
```

Comment: ```` f=(n,x=1)=>x<n?f(x,n):x>n?f(+[...n+''].reduce((p,i)=>p*i||p)+n,x):n ````

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>18</s> 14 bytes

```
ḊḢDo1P+Ʋ;µQƑ¿Ḣ
```

Input is a singleton array.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjq6HOxa55BsGaB/bZH1oa@CxiYf2A0X@Wysdbjc8tsT9/39DHQVTHQVDSx0FM2MA)

#### How it works

```
ḊḢDo1P+Ʋ;µQƑ¿Ḣ  Main link. Argument: [n]

            ¿   While...
          QƑ      all elements of the return value are unique...
         µ          execute the chain to the left.
Ḋ                     Dequeue; remove the first item.
 Ḣ                    Head; extract the first item.
                      This yields the second item of the return value if it has
                      at least two elements, 0 otherwise.
       Ʋ              Combine the links to the left into a chain.
  D                     Take the decimal digits of the second item.
   o1                   Perform logical OR with 1, replacing 0's with 1's.
     P                  Take the product.
      +                 Add the product with the second item.
        ;             Prepend the result to the previous return value.
             Ḣ  Head; extract the first item.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>111</s> <s>95</s> 93 bytes

Using unpacking in `replace(*'01')` as in @Rod [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163143/66855)
-18 bytes thanks to @Lynn

```python
l=[1,input()]
while cmp(*l):l[0]+=eval('*'.join(`l[0]`.replace(*'01')));l.sort()
print l[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxBCsMgEEDRfU7hzhkbRLNriycJAUMQYpnoYGxDTm@a7efx@axrTkNr5Ebbx8TfCjh1xxopiGVjUIQvGs30cOE3E0gl9SfHBP6OXpfANC8BlDRWIuKb9J7L/9FxiamKWwnRmn1e)

Comment: Ah, and the loop condition can be `while cmp(*l)`, also!

Comment: @Lynn Yes! Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 78 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b=1:a*(a==b)or f(*sorted([a+eval('*'.join(`a`.replace(*'01'))),b]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcvRCoMgFAbgV@nOc1zI3F0DnySCfpcyw1RMBnt667v/yr99c3r17k3EYTcMGK3Rb0iCMZZzHTzJM9fmNprxcD9EElKoPYdEK1ZVXYn4OJLiqQUzj3Zh7qWG1O6qJ@4X)

Comment: I was working on solution with lambda, but got stuck with shortcircuting for couple minutes, good job!

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 65 bytes

```hs
(!1)
a!b|a>b=b!a|a<b=(a+product[read[d]|d<-show a,d>'0'])!b|1<2=a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcsxDoMgGAbQvaeASUg1Kd2agBexDh/8Uk2pErBx4ezSvv3NyO8phOrNswqu5AXcFvTWWI4CbY3ANaaNvm4f0gQaaCykuzxvB0NLfXNrRvkvSt8N6gfLygyLaVl3JjxTD1lP5wNeuXYuxh8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 13 bytes

```
→UΞm¡S+ȯΠf±dΘ
```

Takes input as a singleton list.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9odXNr///ihpJVzp5twqFTK8ivzqBmwrFkzpj///9bNjNd)

## Explanation

```
                 Implicit input, e.g 5
            Θ    Prepend a zero to get  [0,5]
   m             Map the following over [0,5]
    ¡              Iteratatively apply the following function, collecting the return values in a list
           d         Convert to a list of digits
         f±          keep only the truthy ones
       ȯΠ            then take the product
     S+              add that to the original number
                After this map, we have [[0,1,2,4,8,16,22,26,38,62...],[5,10,11,12,14,18,26,38,62,74...]]
  Ξ             Merge the sorted lists:  [0,1,2,4,5,8,10,11,12,14,16,18,22,26,26,38,38,62,62,74...]
 U              Take the longest unique prefix: [0,1,2,4,5,8,10,11,12,14,16,18,22,26]
→               Get the last element and implicitely output: 26
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>126</s> 125 bytes

```python
m=[1]
n=[int(input())]
while not{*m}&{*n}:
 for l in m,n:l+=l[-1]+eval('*'.join(str(l[-1]).replace(*'01'))),
print({*m}&{*n})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc2xCsIwEIDhPU@RydyltRgKDoU8SchQJNLI9RJiVKT02SM6uP7D9@d3XRKPra3WGS/YusgVIudHBUQvXkukIDnVTa/7YdO8T0JeU5EkI8u154k6S@5ofBeeM4HSarilyHCvBX4dhxIyzZcAWp2MQsRe5PK9/Els7Tx@AA)

Take the input as string

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), 99 bytes

```java
n->{for(int x=1;x!=n;n+=(""+n).chars().reduce(1,(a,b)->a*(b>48?b-48:1)))x^=x<n?n^(n=x):0;return n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY/LTsMwEEX3@YqhK7ttLCIKKjVOxZIFYlGxQlRyXsUhmUT2pCSq8u3Ban8gq9HVnNGcW@qzDsvsdzJ121iC0mfRkalE0WFKpkGxlEFaaefgXRuESwDwhvSJ2g4fbW41NRYKUBOG8aVoLDNI0KtI9ncKJa4UWyxWyEX6o61jXNg869KcRWum1wkPY71kSbzZ7pNws91FnPP@qPoX3OORoer57l7anDqLgHKcpH/edkllUnCkyY9zYzKovRg7kDV4@voGbU@OXz3hplyDAsz/roFxeV0cBkd5LZqOROvvqEJWi0Lotq2GV@cLMu8yF32cj0bP89mnhxs7BuP0Dw)

Mostly an iterative port of [Arnauld's JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163144/16236), so go upvote him!

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 23 bytes

```
ð⁹1,Dḟ0P+Ʋ⁸Ð¡€f/©µ1#ṛ®Ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATUAyv9qZWxsef//w7DigbkxLEThuJ8wUCvGsuKBuMOQwqHigqxmL8KpwrUxI@G5m8Ku4bii////NQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 50 bytes

tacit style function definition

```
[:{.@(e.~#])/[:(+[:*/@(*#])(#~10)&#:)^:(<453)"0,&1
```

if the argument (say 63) were pasted into a REPL expression it could be 45 e.g.

```
{.(e.~#])/(+[:*/@(*#])(#~10)&#:)^:(<453)"0]1,63
```

- `,&1` append 1 to generate search sequence as well as argument's sequence
- `^:(<453)"0` iterates each until 1mio is reached in 1's sequence
- `+ [: */@(*#]) (#~10)&#:` fork adds to hook which does the product of digits
- `(e.~ # ])/` uses repeat item if exists to get intersection of lists
- `{.` return only the first common value

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZBbTsMwEEX/s4oRlVq7j7ghUAkXpIoFsIGqlYIzSQ2NHfyAQqVuPdihleCLrxmPx@f63peue3pMoYDW6BYNVF4JJ7WCEiupZGyTCh44rPkxXRFMT4MNZWtOJms@ZisyDkcyOGVzOhxwuuXk/uY2p1fz6TBLkp5sat@gciAttIVxoCsoFOChNWhtxIcaBY7phf4fe5NNFzkkiW20d613QCAyllBBmNMf3Z1zreWMCV1irfdVal0hXvEgdoWqMRW6YW8ebTRoWbbIs/yOlbKWbhaSKL1wM4thQQm0Pc@ikUFEKmEw@rHw/Ann1ehJaTX7QqNDcEI2xR56mI1Xwem71P7M2ekPCH85JwEXlSQ0MQYyCVHDxT789X89p79dj@KbbLSEvgLtum8)

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>110</s> 86 bytes

```r
o=c(1,1:9);o=o%o%o%o%o;o=c(o%o%o)
x=c(1,n);while((x=sort(x))<x[2])x[1]=(x+o[x+1])[1]
x
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##K/qfZ2tm/D/fNlnDUMfQylLTOt82XxUKrUHCYJYmVwVYRZ6mdXlGZk6qhkaFbXF@UYlGhaamTUW0UaxmRbRhrK1GhXZ@dIW2YawmkMdV8f8/AA)

**previous version 110:**

```r
f=function(x){if((x[1]=x[1]+(c((y=(y=c(1,1:9))%o%y%o%y)%o%y))[x[1]+1])==x[2]){x[1]}else{f(sort(x))}}
f(c(1,n))
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##HU/basMwDH3fVxwoBYutD9lg0IH/om8lD8GRM8NiB8seTUO@PVUiJHF0OxzlLdrvLwAn3H4ZXR7qyLEgCKZOhHuEiE7QRQWFB86bt75GV0KK5kFL8MY87k1r9/RunDGzVXem@Wh@rkTndJ73OADR/VhrWrJ68NnSstcr/wkv3kjKRTlpXd@82Rki0XaCS@NUCwukjoLkMeXUV1cOHFO8PDkn9GEI2qoTSsL1MJUsodevkNnVLCoZF/xznnXC3gcX9NftBQ)